# Failed to open stream - XAMPP

Tags: php, html, sql, href

I am having an issue.

- OS - Windows 10
- Developing Website on XAMPP v30204
- Using PHP

Calling dynamic data from sql via link examples:

`http://127.0.0.1/abbgi/category-page.php?category_id=73` - works, pulls all data from the SQL database and shows correctly via html in table.

`http://127.0.0.1/abbgi/index.php?content=in-ground-basketball-goal-installation.php` - works ( this is static content on a page withing main directory that shows correctly within the index.php content shell )

`http://127.0.0.1/abbgi/index.php?content=category-page.php?category_id=88` - bad - ERROR:

> Warning: include(category-page.php?category_id=88): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\abbgi\index.php on line 98
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'category-page.php?category_id=88' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\abbgi\index.php on line 98

Code on index.php:

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['content']))
        include("home.php");                    
    else
    {
        $content = $_REQUEST['content'];
        $nextpage = $content;
        include($nextpage);
    }
?>
```

It seems that when the link includes index.php pulling data from sql that it breaks.

Comment: Please be aware that your application basically displays any file requested. I hope it's just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` to separate data instead of `?`

```
http://127.0.0.1/abbgi/index.php?content=category-page.php&category_id=88
```

You have used `?` instead of `&` after `content=category-page.php`